# match IP ranges that contains same first 2 blocks from all lines and export the result

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, awk, grep, notepad++

Using norepad++, I am simply trying to find a way to match the ranges that has the same 2 blocks from all the lines. For example, the list would look like this, sorted alphabetically.

```
10.10.223.255
10.10.232.122
10.5.246.33
108.252.56.36
108.252.99.23
135.236.12.36
142.58.36.36
142.58.88.36
228.36.236.5
69.65.23.46
```

Expected result:

```
10.10.223.255
10.10.232.122
108.252.56.36
108.252.99.23
142.58.36.36
142.58.88.36
```

Is it possible to do this on notepad++? I just need first 2 octets from the list which I can do using this regex:

using this regex to export

```
^.*(^\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){1}[0-9]{1,3}\b.).*
```

by replacing it with: \1

now I am stuck on bookmarking the matched octets from the list. It would be great to save the results (matched and non-matched) to separated txt files.

Any help will be appreciated.

It doesn't has to be only notepad++, python, awk, perl, grep is also welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: If a range you want to capture can be restarted later in the file, your sample data should show that, else you should indicate **in the body of your question**, that "data will be sorted" or "will not restart ranges later in the file". Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take your Text File, Sort it, and compare looking for any IPs that start with the same first two Octets and create the new files for matched and non -matched IPs.

```cmd
@( SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_SrcFile=C:\Admin\SE\IP_Source.txt"
  SET "_MatchFile=C:\Admin\SE\IP_Match.txt"
  SET "_NoMatchFile=C:\Admin\SE\IP_NonMatch.txt"
  SET "_TmpIP="
  SET "_Matched="
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B
)

:Main
echo 1
  FOR /F "Tokens=1-2* delims=." %%A IN ('
    TYPE "%_SrcFile%" ^| SORT
  ') DO (
    REM Check lastIP if it wasn't already matched
    IF NOT DEFINED _Matched (
      ECHO= !_TmpIP! | FIND /I " %%A.%%B." && (
        ECHO.!_TmpIP!>>"%_MatchFile%"
      ) || ( 
        ECHO.!_TmpIP!>>"%_NoMatchFile%"
      )
    )
    REM Check Current IP to see if it matches
    ECHO= !_TmpIP! | FIND /I " %%A.%%B." && (
      ECHO.%%A.%%B.%%C>>"%_MatchFile%"
      SET "_Matched=1" 
    ) || (
      SET "_Matched="
    )
    SET "_TmpIP=%%A.%%B.%%C"
  )
  REM Check if the last IP was unmatched
  IF NOT DEFINED _Matched ( 
    ECHO.!_TmpIP!>>"%_NoMatchFile%"
  )
GOTO :EOF
```

### This was my Source File

```cmd
10.10.232.122
10.10.223.255
10.5.246.33
135.236.12.36
142.58.36.36
142.58.88.36
228.36.236.5
69.65.23.46
108.252.56.36
108.252.99.23
103.24.107.75
103.24.125.33
103.245.16.42
```

### This was the result in Matched.txt:

```cmd
10.10.223.255
10.10.232.122
103.24.107.75
103.24.125.33
108.252.56.36
108.252.99.23
142.58.36.36
142.58.88.36
```

### This was the result in NotMatched.txt

```cmd
10.5.246.33
103.245.16.42
135.236.12.36
228.36.236.5
69.65.23.46
```

Comment: Thanks Ben but the script is not working, it is giving error with every line: 'FIND: ‘/I’: No such file or directory
FIND: ‘ 96.30.’: No such file or directory' I am using it on windows, by creating .bat file.

Comment: @Bawzz ahh I left a command in there from another script at the top from what I was testing when I copied it over, my bad -- should be working now

Comment: @Bawzz And also had a chance to test and make a little update so you will see the matches all echo on screen as well as save in the files.

Comment: Thank you Ben it is working now, but it is also saving the IPs, where the first octet is matched. for example: the list `103.24.107.75
103.24.125.33
103.245.16.42` it is saving the last one as well.

Comment: @Bawzz  I can not reproduce this issue, please see the updated test I ran, perhaps you grabbed the code from before the last update?

Comment: Hello Ben, just tested the latest version, the issue was solved. Everything is working properly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **EmEditor**, click the **Advanced Filter** button in the **Filter** toolbar.

[image: EmEditor - Filter toolbar]

In the **Advanced Filter** dialog box, enter these three IP address CDIR notations in the list:

```
10.10.0.0/16
142.58.0.0/16
108.252.0.0/16
```

and make sure the **Number Range** and **Logical Disjunction (OR) to the Previous Conditions** options are set for all items in the list. Click the **Filter** button.

[image: EmEditor - Advanced Filter]

Then you can click the **Extract All** button in the **Filter** toolbar to get your expected result (matched.txt).

To extract non-matches, click the **Advanced Filter** button in the **Filter** toolbar again, select all items in the list, and set the **Negative** option, and clear the **Logical Disjunction (OR) to the Previous Conditions** option.

[image: EmEditor - Advanced Filter]